# Importing Scala companion object in file where it is defined

Tags: scala

I have a ThisThing.scala file containing:

```
class ThisThing() extends BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState]
object ThisThing {
  sealed trait ThisEvent
  case class Load(uuid: UUID) extends ThisEvent
  case object Stop extends ThisEvent

  sealed trait ThisState
  case object Loading extends ThisState
  case object Loaded extends ThisState
}
```

Where ThisThing needs to be parameterized by the types of event and state it handles. This requires also having an import:

```
import ThisThing._
```

Which feels really strange, to have to import something from the same file.  I'm guessing I'm doing something non idiomatic and that there is a better way to structure it?

Comment: Any chance it's about Akka's FSM, or did I guess incorrectly?

Comment: It's an FSM, but not using Akka.  I'm working on a ScalaFX-based app that needs to also simulate (in a long-running Future, since it shouldn't be done in the JavaFX thread) and render (in yet another long-running Future).  I looked at Akka but I didn't see a clear way to schedule things so that both the simulation and rendering could be easily maintained at a particular frame rate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot comment on ScalaFX. As you see, the answer to your question *can* depend on the context (i.e. it seems as if it would be ok if it was an Akka FSM). I don't know whether a similar argument applies to ScalaFX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit strange, but in principle valid.

It's non-idiomatic, because you are trying to *hide* `ThisEvent` and `ThisState` inside `ThisThing`'s companion object, but at the same time you *expose* these types in the signature of `ThisThing ... extends BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState]`.

The problem is that not only *you*, but also every *user* of `ThisThing` will have to unpack `ThisThing`s companion object in order to write down the type `BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState]`:

```
// much later, in someone else's code in a galaxy far, far away 
import foo.bar.baz.ThisThing.{ThisEvent, ThisState} // awkward to use!
val t: BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState] = new ThisThing
```

So... If you think that someone will want to access `ThisEvent` and `ThisState` later, then move them out of the `ThisThing` companion.

If you think that *nobody should even know* that `ThisThing` is actually a 
`BaseThing[X, Y]`, then you have an abstraction leak anyway, and you could handle it by declaring `ThisThing` as a trait, and then implementing a concrete class that extends both `ThisThing` and `BaseThing` inside the `ThisThing`'s companion object, so that `BaseThing` does not leak to the outside.

To summarize, it's one of two scenarios:

- Scenario 1: `BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState]` should be visible from the outside. In this case, `ThisEvent` and `ThisState` are buried a bit too deep in the companion object, and are therefore awkward to access.
- Scenario 2: `BaseThing[ThisEvent, ThisState]` is an abstraction leak.

*Just a random guess:* If you just want to parameterize something like an Akka FSM, leave it as it is now. I think it's common, because nobody outside should really care how an actor is actually implemented. It's impossible to obtain an explicit reference to `ThisThing` anyway, because all you ever see are the `ActorRef`s, so that the actual instance is hidden. In this case the "abstraction leak" isn't too critical, because nobody ever sees an actual instance of your FSM.